# How can I get a search filter to loop through MULTIPLE data types in a stock items table, and narrow down what results displayed?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, search

Please excuse me if I use the wrong terminology.

I have working javascript code in a php file which filters what data is displayed in a table of stock items on a WordPress page front-end.

i.e. search by serial number and the more you type the less items are shown on a WordPress front-end until one unique item is found.

Client wants to be able to search in a variety of ways - and I can change which single topic is being searched e.g. I can get it to search by dispatch number, serial, asset type, description etc, but cannot get the search to look at all the topics. i.e. the id in the code only allows me to choose one of the elements

If I change the "1" here to "2" or "3" etc it chnages the search focus from column 1 to 2 to 3 etc.

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
```

Can anyone suggest how to search all the data at the same time?

```
<script>
    function helloWorld() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, sn, ty, own, i, id;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("adminTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var data = new Array();
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if(td.children[0].checked) {
                    sn = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
                    ty = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[9];
                    id = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[10];
                    own = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[11];
                    var record = {serial: sn.textContent || sn.innerText, type: ty.textContent || ty.innerText, id: id.textContent || id.innerText, owner: own.textContent || own.innerText};
                    data.push(record);
                }
            }
        }

        if(data.length > 0) {
            var uri = JSON.stringify(data);
            var res = encodeURIComponent(uri); 
            window.location.href = '../stock?transferData='.concat(res);
        }
    }
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("adminTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3xFu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This javascript https://fusejs.io/ search library might be all you need.  You might need to map your WP data first but this will let you search for anything you want.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I am such a novice that I'd really benefit from someone hopefully tweaking what's already there! (I'm just not experienced enough to start using alternative solutions at the moment!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace

```
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

by this

(Set column numbers you need in the [1,4,5] list)

```
  var columns = [1,4,5];
  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query  
  for (var j=0, lenj=columns.length; j < lenj; j++) {     
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[columns[j]];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Assuming you mean to literally copy and paste your code into the second part of the myfunction section then this unfortunately didn't work and stopped any search filtering working.

Comment: Can you open it in Google Chrome and open Developers Tools (`Ctrl+Shift+i`) and then Console tab and paste the red text/error here? Also I assume you entered the correct column numbers in the [1,4,5] list.

Comment: Also realize that my new code has 4 `}` at the end now, where previous code had 3 `}`. So after you paste there is a total of 5 `}` at the end, just before the `</script>` tag.